# Finding capacitive load driving capability of a Sine wave crystal oscillator

Tags: impedance, pll, sine

I will be using Crystek [CCSS-945X-25-100.000](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/94/CCSS-945-1382282.pdf) sine wave oscillator to drive the reference CLKin pins of TI PLL IC [LMK04832](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmk04832.pdf)

This sine wave oscillator will be on a separate PCB which we are calling as "CLOCK DISTRIBUTION BOARD".

Sine wave clock from "CLOCK DISTRIBUTION BOARD" will be connected to main board which has LMK04832 PLL through a SMA cable.

I have checked the CMOS version of the oscillator : [CVHD-950](https://www.crystek.com/crystal/spec-sheets/vcxo/CVHD-950.pdf).

In datasheet of CMOS oscillator ,they mentioned the load as 15pF.

Now I need to know how much load in capacitance, this sine wave oscillator version can drive because this SMA cable will be having some capacitance and also LMK04832 refclock inputs will be having some capacitance.

***Is there any way to know the value of load capacitance, this sine wave oscillator can drive ,from the available oscillator specification in datasheet like 5dBm into 50 Ohms i.e, how to convert 5dBm into 50 Ohms to 5dBm into ... pF?***

Comment: This seems to be asking *exactly* the same things as your [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/469845/driving-high-impedance-load-with-crystek-sine-wave-oscillator-ccss-945x-25-100). It is not permitted for someone to ask the same thing in multiple questions. Therefore I'm voting to close this one as a duplicate of your previous one. If you have any new information, please edit that previous question and add it there. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Driving high impedance load with Crystek Sine Wave Oscillator- CCSS-945X-25-100.000](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/469845/driving-high-impedance-load-with-crystek-sine-wave-oscillator-ccss-945x-25-100)

Answer (score 0):

A sine Xtal Osc will have a 50 Ohms source impedance and designed for a 50 Ohm Load.

**+5dBm @ 50 Ohms = 1.125 Vpp ~ 3 mW**

A "CMOS" Xtal Osc will be a logic level Square wave and thus rise time (3ns) depends on rated load Capacitance (15 pF typ) and internal RdsOn.  This is because RC = T for 64% swing  so they are saying @ 15 pF, 3 ns, with 60% swing that RdsOn = 3ns/15pF = 333 Ohm (worst case) but actually it is ~ 25 Ohms. +/-50% for most 3.3V CMOS logic.

**+/- 24 mA max out does not state output level but if  "25 Ohm" logic is used then the voltage will drop 33% with 50 Ohm load.**  which is more like 12dBm.

I picked a random 3.6V max logic inverter which I expect to be "25 Ohm logic" is closer to 22 Ohm... but *close enuf for government work.*
[image]

**But you probably need the square wave logic source.**

However for spurious harmonic EMI reasons ,  3ns rise time will have harmonics up to 100MHz or so , you may  want controlled impedance with guard grd tracks.